# Edit Cuda Texture Object

Tags: cuda

I've created a texture object which references 2d pitched memory given a specified `Width` & `Height`. Nothing special there. I can use this texture object to read from the texture and make use of all of the texture 'stuff'.

My question regards **how to edit the texture** and is quite straight forward. Some examples show the creation of a `cudaSurfaceObject_t` and use `surf2Dwrite()` in a kernel to edit the texture.

**Why should or shouldn't I use a surface instead of the raw memory via the memory pointer to edit the texture contents?**

Is this the main difference? The surface object will ensure that a read from the texture gets the correct value from texture cache. Editing the raw buffer will not update a value currently stored in the texture cache, thus a subsequent read of the updated value may not contain the correct value?

Assign 2d pitched memory:

```
float* d_MyBuffer;
unsigned int Pitch;
cudaMallocPitch<float>(&d_MyBuffer, &Pitch, Width * sizeof(float), Height);
```

Create the texture object:

```
cudaTextureObject_t t_MyTexture;

cudaResourceDesc resDescr;
memset(&resDescr, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
resDescr.resType = cudaResourceType::cudaResourceTypePitch2D;
resDescr.res.pitch2D.desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
resDescr.res.pitch2D.devPtr = d_MyBuffer;
resDescr.res.pitch2D.height = Height;
resDescr.res.pitch2D.pitchInBytes = Pitch;
resDescr.res.pitch2D.width = Width;

cudaTextureDesc  texDescr;
memset(&texDescr, 0, sizeof(cudaTextureDesc));
texDescr.normalizedCoords = 1;
texDescr.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;
texDescr.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
texDescr.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
texDescr.addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
texDescr.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;

cudaCreateTextureObject(&t_MyTexture, &resDescr, &texDescr, NULL);
```

Create surface:

```
cudaSurfaceObject_t s_MySurface;

cudaResourceDesc surfRes;
memset(&surfRes, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
surfRes.resType = cudaResourceType::cudaResourceTypePitch2D;
surfRes.res.pitch2D.desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
surfRes.res.pitch2D.devPtr = d_MyBuffer;
surfRes.res.pitch2D.height = Height;
surfRes.res.pitch2D.pitchInBytes = Pitch;
surfRes.res.pitch2D.width = Width;

cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&s_MySurface,&surfRes)
```

In a kernel should I prefer to use:

```
surf2Dwrite(value, s_MySurface, x, y);
```

Or in a kernel should I prefer to use:

```
d_MyBuffer[x + Pitch*y] = value;
```

I apologize for any typos in the code. This is more of a conceptual question rather than a coding syntax question.

Comment: The texture cache is *non-coherent*. Any changes applied directly to the storage underlying a texture may or *may not* be reflected in the texture cache. Presumably you want changes to a texture reflected on the next use of the texture, so this approach is not suitable.

Comment: If I update the texture underlying buffer in one kernel dispatch and then access the updated texture in a subsequent kernel dispatch, wouldn't the cache stay coherent?

Other than the caching issue, is there anything you can think of as a benefit in either method?

Comment: Texture cache is flushed as part of kernel launch, so updating the memory underlying a texture is guaranteed to be reflected for the *next* kernel running in the same stream, correct. As long as you don't try to read from a texture *after* modifying the underlying memory *in the same kernel*, your code will be fine (I have used this approach in production code).

Comment: An example implementation is contained in the cuda simpleSurfaceWrite sample code, demonstrating a surface write kernel followed by a texture read kernel, where the surface write goes to the same underlying data read in the texture access subsequently.  As already indicated, attempting to do a surface write (or any other type of modification of the underlying data) *in the same kernel* as a subsequent texture read on the same underlying data is not guaranteed to give predictable results.

Comment: I got misled by the above code and tried using pitched memory for a surface object, but it doesn't work. It seems a surface object only accepts cudaArray and not pitch2D.